# Will using class.forname multiple times cause memory leak? (running inside tomcat)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, classloader

1) If I use the following Class.forName() is called multiple times, will it cause memory leaks?

```
Class.forName("MyClass")
```

2) Or, is tomcat's WebAppClassLoader going to check whether `"MyClass"` is already loaded and use the cached instance instead.

3) If the answer to question (2) is 'no' then, will the previously loaded class gets garbage collected, if I have switched on PermGen sweeping on and set relevant jvm parameters.

If I want to avoid reloading of class, what is the best way to use class instance cache. Can I store class instance as HashMap

Comment: I don't think it should leak memory as long it is loaded from the same classloader in the first place. Also ClassLoader changing over time also sounds unlikely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) No, one class definition is only loaded once by any given classloader. After that, it is kept in memory (in PermGen space) and reused on subsequent references to the class, till the classloader exists. This is independent of how the class is referenced: via `Class.forName`, `ClassLoader.loadClass` or whatever.

The same class definition can be loaded into different classloaders multiple times though (resulting in multiple class token objects in memory). These count as totally different classes, which can't be cast to each other, even if they were loaded from exactly the same class file.

2) Yes

3) N/A

4) the referenced article mentions that the class is reloaded in a different classloader, so my explanation under 1) applies.

Comment: I suppose this is going to use the same classloader which will be this web-application's classloader provided by tomcat.

Comment: @samarjitsamanta, most probably yes, although I am not a Tomcat expert so don't take my word as a guarantee :-)

Comment: yes the 4th question's answer was a bit stupid part of me that mixed up class loader and class instance :) I realized it and removed the question which is irrelevant. thanks for quick answwer.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation:

Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.

I see no indication the class should be loaded again. It simply returns it indicating it would be safe to call multiple times.